# My app showing doen't compatible for nexus 5?

Tags: android, android-webview

My app running well on devices except nexus 5. In my manifst file I have added

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />



   <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Also my app is hybrid. 
Is anybody having same problem??
Can anyone suggest me some solution what i am missing exactly??
Any help is appricate.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not running well". Is it not compatible according to the Google Play Store?

Comment: yes it showing not compatible message on google play

Comment: Have you already fixed this problem? Would you like to updated new answer? The answer of @Ram not works with me.

Comment: @AlexTran Ram solution is working for me...using his solution my is compatible for Nexus 7 also

Comment: Have you no need to add <compatible-screens> to your manifest.xml file? Only use <supports-screens>?

Comment: yes i removed  <compatible-screens> and just addeded the  <supports-screens> part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file.

```
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: I followed your answer and the coding of the person ask this question, but can not work as for me. Please tell more detail ...

Comment: @AlexTran The problem because of different dimension of the devices.You can fix it by alter your images for two different dpi.xhdpi for nexus 7 under the resolution of 1920 x 1200 pixels rate.xxhdpi for nexus 5 under the resolution of 1080 x 1920 pixels rate.

Comment: You mean I will create folder layout-xhdpi-1920x1200 and layout-xxhdpi-1080x1920? how about folder drawable? only need use drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi?

Comment: @AlexTran what ever the folder name under drawable folder.But the image for nexus should be the 1080 x 1920 pixels rate.for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140135/app-logo-in-actionbar-appears-larger-on-tablet-vs-phone/22140808#22140808

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 5 state is `xxhdpi` (always = 480), so need update the manifest.xml file as here :

```
<compatible-screens>

    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="445"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="small" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- Nexus 5 : 445ppi -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="445"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="445"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <!-- all x large size screens -->

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="445"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
```

It's really necessary.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Change `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` to `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` and install api 19 in your SDK Manager.

Hope this helps.